# Broken switch statement in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm having issues with switch statements in TypeScript

Tried on multiple code editors, I'm trying to use switch (true) but for some reason the code is failing in the switch statement.

```
const todoList: string[] | null = [];

function pushItemToTodoList(item: string) {
  //COMPILES!!
  if (todoList !== undefined && todoList !== null && todoList.length) {
    if (todoList.length >= 5) {
      console.log("LIST IS FULL!");
    }
  }

  //DOESN'T COPMILE!!
  switch (true) {
    case todoList !== undefined && todoList !== null && todoList.length:
      if (todoList.length >= 5) { //todoList is null???
        console.log("LIST IS FULL!");
      }
      break;
  }
}

pushItemToTodoList("clean house");
```

[here is a picture of the error, thank you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68U6e.png)

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to use `switch` here?

Comment: I don’t see any use of using switch and it’s not how you use it . You can explain what are you trying to achieve so that it could be answered.

Comment: @MarkusZeller it's a bit of a hack but it's a valid usage. Since you normally do `switch (x)` and then try to match `x` to each `case` you can also pass `true` and then expect each `case` to evaluate to either `true` or `false`. Ideally, you will have multiple `case` statements that are all mutually exclusive. I don't think it's a *good* technique but it's a possible way to write a `switch`.

Comment: @MarkusZeller that's not how && works: it will never reach that block. It uses strict equality, not truthiness and it evaluates to a number (todoList.length) not boolean `true`.

Comment: @VLAZ I'm getting Object is possibly 'null'

Comment: Hi guys I uploaded a picture please check it out thank you

Comment: @samjamz edit your question with the error itself, not a link to a picture. Please take the tour so you know how to ask an appropriate question.

Comment: @JaredSmith I listed the error in the code

Comment: You can always assert to the compiler that the list isn't null: `((todoList as string[]).length >= 5)` but you still have all the other problems.

Comment: @JaredSmith or `todoList!.length >= 5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The switch statement by itself does not fail.
It simpy does not tolerate case statements with variables. nor conditional operators, only static values.
At compiling time, the switch statement builds an index of all the static values in the case statements and their jump positions.
You cannot use variables in a case statement because at compile time, these variables are not supposed to be calculated or even exist.
Switch - Case statements are super performant, because of indexes with static values and jump positions being pre-compiled.
There is a way to solve this specific problem though, combining boolean logic with algebra in the switch statement and static values in the case statements.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem, and you are describing how switch works in c, not Typescript. I can assure you that switch does indeed tolerate variables of the correct type at compile time in typescript.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with a variable of the correct type ?  Do you mean that results in the switch statement has to have the same type as the values in case statements ?

Comment: The Typescript compiler [does not compile the switch into a jump table at compile time](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/DYUwLgBAZg9jEF4IHIAWBLZBuAUDgzgO7pgDGqEAFGAE4CuIAlBAN44QSkCG+I0ciBEjSYAXJxgA7fDFAA6YDADmlZLQbJGWCACMaILgGtcHACYgoXOsDDjSUmfMUrkl4L024AvjiA). You're thinking of C. So it's totally valid to use variables in case statements as long as they have the correct type. Your answer is factually incorrect.

Comment: The OPs actual problems are that they are not using the [proper type guard syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to satisfy the compiler that the array is not null, and that the && operator returns the last truthy value of the expression which in this case is a number (the list length), and it does not strictly equal boolean true (the value being switched on), so the case statement is never reached.

Answer (score 1):

I can see what you were trying to do here, but you might want to improve your example because it’s really not conveying a good use case. `switch (true)` can be a clever trick (some would call it a “hack” ;), but you may want to take inspiration from [MDN’s page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#an_alternative_to_if...else_chains) for some good examples.

The reason your code is not compiling is simply because TypeScript does not support type guards in `case` expressions beyond [narrowing discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#exhaustiveness-checking). In Ryan Cavanaugh’s words, it’s just [“not a commmon enough pattern”](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8934).

I’m not happy with that either.

Answer (score 0):

That is not how a switch statement works.

If you would write:

```
switch (true) {
    case todoList:
      if (todoList.length >= 5) { //todoList is null???
        console.log("LIST IS FULL!");
      }
      break;
  }
```

it would work, because in the switch statement you are checking if the case is true.

Switch statements take primitive values, such as booleans, strings, numbers etc.

The way you tried to use the switch statement is more complex and would only work with an if statement.

Comment: Technically this isn't wrong...but it's still completely pointless. There's still no reason to use `switch` here instead of an `if` statement.

Comment: "*Switch statements take primitive values, such as booleans, strings, numbers etc.*" and this `switch` does take a primitive `true`. You probably mean the *case* statements but they can actually take any expression that will be compared to what is passed to the `switch`. So, if you do `switch (true)` and one of the `case` statement conditions evaluates to `true`, then it will be fired.